# Label TapGestureRecognizer works with Tapped, but not with Command

Tags: maui, uitapgesturerecognizer

I have followed James Montemagno's excellent [.Net MAUI for Beginners](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLdo4fOcmZ0oUBAdL2NwBpDs32zwGqb9DY) series. In it, he uses a TapGestureRecognizer Command to go to a detail page for the item tapped. I downloaded his repo and tested and it works fine in VS 2022 v17.4.0 Preview 1.0.

I pretty much copied his code directly into mine and it doesn't work in my project for some reason. Now Tapped *does* work fine and goes to a new page, but when I use that method it wants me to pass in the view model, which I can't figure out. So I thought James' Command method might work better, but can't get it to even call the TapCommand code - nothing happens when clicking/tapping on the label.

So Edit Profile works. Edit Account does not. Here's the code:

XAML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             x:Class="CRUMSMobile.Views.Settings.UserSettings"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:CRUMSMobile.ViewModels.Settings"
             x:DataType="viewmodel:UserSettingsViewModel"
             Title="Settings">
    
    <VerticalStackLayout>
        <Label Text="Account Settings"
               FontSize="16"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               TextColor="DarkGray"
               TextTransform="Uppercase"
               VerticalOptions="Start" 
               HorizontalOptions="Start" 
               Margin="20,20,0,30"/>

        <Label Text="Edit Account"
            HorizontalOptions="Start"
            FontSize="14"
            Margin="20,0,0,30">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer 
                        Command="{Binding Source={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type viewmodel:UserSettingsViewModel}}, Path=TapCommand}"
                        CommandParameter="EditAccount"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>

        <Label Text="Edit profile"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               FontSize="14"
               Margin="20,0,0,30">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="Edit_Profile_Tapped" />
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>
        </Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Code behind:

```
public partial class UserSettings : ContentPage
{
    public UserSettings()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Edit_Profile_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Navigation.PushAsync(new EditProfile());
    }
}
```

View Model:

```
public partial class UserSettingsViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    public UserSettingsViewModel()
    {
    }

    [RelayCommand]
    async Task Tap(string s)
    {
        if (s == "EditAccount")
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(EditAccount));
        }
    }
}
```

And here's the constructor for the EditAccount page:

```
public partial class EditAccount : ContentPage
{
    public EditAccount(EditAccountViewModel viewModel)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        BindingContext = viewModel;
        _ = GetUserAccount();
    }

[...]
```

Comment: Have you stepped through the code in the debugger to verify if Tap is being called?

Comment: You shouldn't need all that in the Binding that you have right now. Just use `Command="{Binding TapCommand}"` should be enough for how you're using it. Also, I don't see you setting the `BindingContext` in the `UserSettings` page?

Comment: Thanks @GeraldVersluis, I followed and commented on your .NET MAUI YouTube videos and they helped a lot.  I did try passing in the viewModel to UserSettings like "public UserSettings(UserSettingsViewModel viewModel)", but then my call to that page didn't work:  "Navigation.PushAsync(new UserSettings());". I get an error saying I have to pass in the view model parameter and not sure how to do that.

Comment: Thanks, @Jason, I did step through and the Tap command code is never called.  I am not sure why James M. set the Binding using Source and Path, but I'll try Gerald's idea later today and see if it works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @GeraldVersluis suggested, you should use `TapCommand` firstly. Also, if you're using `Shell` to navigate through pages, don't forget to **Register** the routing for `EditAccount page` in `AppShell.xaml.cs`. Here's the detailed steps below for your reference:

**1.** Install the `CommunityToolkit.Mvvm` package in your project.

**2.**
**UserSettings.xaml:**

```
    <VerticalStackLayout>

        <Label Text="Account Settings"
               FontSize="16"
               FontAttributes="Bold"
               TextColor="DarkGray"
               TextTransform="Uppercase"
               VerticalOptions="Start"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               Margin="20,20,0,30"/>
        
        <Label Text="Edit Account"
               HorizontalOptions="Start"
               FontSize="14"
               BackgroundColor="Red"
               Margin="20,0,0,30">
            <Label.GestureRecognizers>
                <TapGestureRecognizer
                     Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
            </Label.GestureRecognizers>

        </Label>
    </VerticalStackLayout>
```

**UserSettings.cs:**

```
public partial class UserSettings : ContentPage
{
      public UserSettings()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            BindingContext = new UserSettingsViewModel();
      }
}
```

**3.** ViewModel for the UserSetting Page:

```
    public partial class UserSettingsViewModel : ObservableObject 
    {

        [RelayCommand]
        async Task Tap()
        {
            await Shell.Current.GoToAsync(nameof(EditAccount));
        }
    }
```

**4.** Register the routing:

```
      public AppShell() 
      {
            InitializeComponent();

            Routing.RegisterRoute(nameof(EditAccount), typeof(EditAccount));
      }
```

Comment: Hurray!  That worked, thank you Alexander.  As a Xamarin/MAUI newbie, I didn't know you could just set BindingContext to a 'new' object like that.  I thought you had to pass it in already defined.