# Only-text button in XAML

Tags: xaml, maui

I need to do a button, which shows only text(without background or border) in XAML.

I had tried it with the code below, but it just hid my button:

```
<Button Text="Forgot Password?" Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="2"
        BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent" TextColor="#89a455"/>
```

How can I implement this using XAML in .Net Maui

Comment: That code looks fine. If it isn't showing, the problem may be elsewhere in your xaml. As a test, remove `BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Transparent"`. Does the button show up? If it still doesn't show, then those attributes are not the cause.

Comment: It was just a weird bug and my code above works just fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a [Label and put a GestureRecognizer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74091971/3225) on it.

```
<Label Text="Edit Account"
       HorizontalOptions="Start"
       FontSize="14"
       BackgroundColor="Red"
       Margin="20,0,0,30">
    <Label.GestureRecognizers>
        <TapGestureRecognizer
             Command="{Binding TapCommand}"/>
    </Label.GestureRecognizers>
</Label>
```

UPDATE: something else to try [Maui Port of TouchEffect](https://github.com/Axemasta/Maui.TouchEffect).

Comment: In what way does the behavior or appearance of this answer different from Maui Button?

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve Buttons have some visual state, which you could add w/ effort.

Comment: For those that come in the future ... hopefuloly Maui starts to support TouchEffect in the Maul Community Toolkit. This is the way I make anything be button like in Xamarin.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/xamarin.communitytoolkit.effects.toucheffect?view=xamarin-community-toolkit-sdk